# Storing uploaded dynamic media in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm making a blog with Django, and I'm wondering where I should store the photos that go along with the articles. Should my media folder go inside the articles app, or in the main project folder? It seems that it should go inside the app so that if I want to add more functionality with another app, it can have its own media folder and keep them separate. However, since I have to add a MEDIA_ROOT, it seems that things are set up so that all media has to go to the same place. Is this the case, or am I not understanding this correctly? Can I assign multiple MEDIA_ROOTS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'correct' way would be to have everything stored in `MEDIA_ROOT`, and each `FileField` could specify its own sub directory using the [`upload_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) keyword argument.

The reason you would want everything stored in a single `MEDIA_ROOT` folder is so that configuring your web server to serve those files statically is simple- just one configuration directive to serve the entire folder (rather than having to configure serving files from multiple locations).

Comment: Then what about static files? In the tutorial, they had me create separate folders for each app's static files

Comment: When you run `collectstatic` it gathers all of those files into a single directory ([`STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#static-root)).